# Weight painting not working

Tags: weight-painting

I'm currently practising with weight painting and I have my armature named - right_arm.L and right_arm.R etc. and I have X-Mirror enabled in the Options, but my Weight Painting on one side isn't showing up on the other. Any suggestions?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: I just tested it out and it worked as soon as I enabled the X-mirror option. Not sure where is the issue there.

Comment: Weird. Don't get that. o_O

Comment: Went back and tested it some more and even reverted back to Factory Settings, but it just won't work for me. Guess all I can do is delete the left side, work on the right and then re-duplicate them.